# A probability problem from BMT 2019 about coin tossing

Tags: probability

The problem is: A fair coin is repeatedly flipped until 2019 consecutive coin flips are the same. Compute the probability that the first and last flips of the coin come up differently.

Here I found the solution provided by organizer. I'm confused by this solution, mainly the answer's explanation for the second added term. And when I tried to substitute the answer $x=\dfrac{2^{2018}-1}{2^{2019}-1}$ into the given relation equation, I found that it does not hold. 
I am not sure where I am going wrong, can someone please explain it for me?

[Here is the original question and solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoM3G.png)

Comment: If you checked the solution and it is wrong, then it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue what that solution is doing.  The very first case in the relation to find $x$ doesn't make sense, as that case would make the first and last flip match, exactly what we *don't* want to have happen in the event measured by $x$.

---

Here's what I think they intended to do:

Let $x$ denote the probability that the first and last flips don't match.

Let's compute $1-x$, which is the probability the first and last flips *do* match.  There are two ways to do this:

- The first $2019$ flips are the same.
- The first $k$ flips are the same, where $0 < k < 2019$, the $(k+1)$th flip differs, and the sequence from the $(k+1)$th flip onwards has the first and last flip not matching.

The first case is simple: it has a probability of $1/2^{2018}$ of happening.

The second case is a bit more complicated, but for each fixed $k$, the probability of getting the first $k$ flips the same and the $(k+1)$th different is $1/2^k$.  The probability of then having the first and last flip not matching is then $x$.

Put together:
$$1-x = \frac1{2^{2018}} + x\sum_{k=1}^{2018}\frac1{2^k} = \frac1{2^{2018}} + x \frac{2^{2018}- 1}{2^{2018}}$$

Solving for $x$ gives
$$x = \frac{2^{2018} - 1}{2^{2019}-1}$$

Comment: Thank you, very clear and understandable answer！